# Cannot arrange a matrix by columns using dplyr

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, coordinates, spatial

recent user here. I was trying to arrange a matrix with 3 columns (SITE, LAT and LON) by SITE using dplyr. This is my code so far

```
sites <- read.table("12sites_lat_long2.txt", header=TRUE,dec=".",sep="\t")


#Order the site object and check the sites positions
sites <- sites %>% dplyr::arrange(SITE)
```

And the error that pops

```
> sites <- sites %>% dplyr::arrange(SITE)
Error in `dplyr::arrange()`:
! Problem with the implicit `transmute()` step.
✖ Problem while computing `..1 = SITE`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_mutate()`:
! object 'SITE' not found
```

This is my data

```
SITE,LAT,LONG
TAD,48.133119,-69.705842
IV,48.034772,-69.340821
LUD,49.161609,-68.173798
SAM,49.130887,-66.500031
NOR,50.163282,-66.467896
PUR,50.151276,-66.325630
NEW,48.263541,-64.735703
PAS,48.017946,-65.265587
BON,48.041124,-65.491133
COR,47.496607,-61.723938
ROO,47.806514,-61.232300
CAO,48.5058323,-64.2231551
```

After that I was pretending to keep only coord for further analyses

```
sites_depth <- dplyr::select(sites,LONG,LAT)
```

Thanx!

Comment: please include your data as code, not images.

Comment: Data should be in text not image

Comment: Be aware your data use comma as column separator and you are reading your data using `\t` as sep. Try `sites <- read.table("12sites_lat_long2.txt", header=TRUE,dec=".",sep=",")`

Comment: When I run `dplyr::arrange(df, SITE)` on sample data it runs fine - as @JilberUrbina states it is likely an issue with your data, which is tough to assess through an image (unless you are as smart as Jilber :)

Comment: In this case it would be helpful if you could run `dput(sites)` and paste all the output into your question. Then we can create a perfect copy of that object and test potential solutions. (But it's very likely an upstream problem where you are not loading the variables successfully.)

Comment: Even after transcribing your data for you, I cannot find a way to reproduce  that data. The top two rows (truncated) are `structure(list(SITE=c("TAD","IV"),LAT=c(48.1,48.0),LONG=c(-69.7,-69.3)),row.names=1:2,class="data.frame")`, and `arrange(quux, SITE)` works, `arrange(quux, SITE2)` fails with `'SITE2' not found`, and other various combinations all fail with different errors or they just work. Your question is unfortunately not reproducible.

Comment: But honestly I think the issue is that your data is being imported incorrectly, as highlighted by JilberUrbina. I'm voting to close, please prove me wrong by [edit]ing your question and giving us something reproducible. Thanks and good  luck!

Comment: As JilberUrbina said it was related to the separators, it solved after changing it to comas and was able to continue. Thnx for the help